# How to prevent apps from launching on iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to create an app that can prevent other apps from running. I want to be able to do this programmatically so that my app can decide when other apps are allowed to be used. Is this possible?

Comment: If you've Jailbreak there are some Apps already on Cydia that feature this...

Comment: Why the downvotes? I want to prevent my kids from using other stuff than the phone and messages app more than one hour each day. Psychologists are warning parents that kids can become depressed if they spend too much time playing games on their phone. It would be nice if I could download an app that could help me achieve this. Then I could let my kids take their phones with them without worrying about excessive use.

Answer (score 5):

No, this is not possible to do on the iPhone.

(And I'm glad.)